# problem with finishing/exiting an activity in android app

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to exit an activity using the code

```
myClass.this.finish();
```

However, the code keeps on executing the lines after this.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code just informs runtime that activity is finished so appropriate actions could be taken and activity is not preserved. But it does not mean `immediate abort`. Just put `return` where necessary.